# OCaml match error

Tags: list, pattern-matching, syntax-error, ocaml

I am trying to add my first two element on my list,

I am getting error on third line, why is that?

```
let addfirsttwo lst =
  match lst with
  | List.hd lst + List.hd (List.tl lst)
;;
```

Comment: What's the error? Please include it in the question body and perhaps the title. (think of people trying to find resolution to the same problem)

Answer (score 1):

You mix two different approaches for extracting information from a list. One is using `List.hd` and `List.tl`, the other is pattern matching.

With the former, you are almost done. You just have to get rid of the pattern 
matching like so:

```
let addfirsttwo lst =
  List.hd lst + List.hd (List.tl lst)
```

I assume however, that your question pertains to some homework where `List.hd` and `List.tl` are forbidden. And, anyway, pattern matching is useful to know.
So the problem with your code is that you did not complete the pattern matching. A pattern matching clause has the form

```
| <some pattern> -> <some expression>
```

The pattern usually cpontains variables which you can then use in the expression. One way to define `List.hd`, for example, is

```
let hd list = match list with
| head::tail -> head
```

Your clause was missing the actual pattern and the `->`. Another way to fix your code, at least the syntax, would have been to provide the missing parts like so:

```
let addfirsttwo lst =
  match lst with
  | _ -> List.hd lst + List.hd (List.tl lst)
```

where _ acts as a wildcard that will match any value at all and not bind any variables. It would not, however, solve the assumed homework constraint.

It is worth noting that the pattern I gave for `hd` does not match all values. It only matches lists of length at least 1. That is fine, as `List.hd` only needs to support non-empty lists. Your function only needs to support lists of length at least 2. So a good starting point for you would be a pattern that matches such lists.